# How can I see the exact gcc command line Xcode 3.2.6 runs when it builds an iphone app?

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am trying to build an lib for iOS from source, and I want to know if there is a way to see what arguments are supplied to gcc when xcode build an app for iOS, so that i can copy those arguments and build my app from command line with only gcc.

I'm using xcode 3.2.6, and some articles suggest gcc command line can be seen from the "Build Result" window, but seems like this is not true in my case.

Anyone know how I can get those arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Build Results window - there is a small icon at the end of each build step that you need to click on to reveal the build commands (and you may also need do drag the divider bar up/down to see these).

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the Build Results window. If you're looking to satisfy curiosity, that's enough. If you really want to build an app at the command line, have a look at `xcodebuild`, which is a command-line entry point to the Xcode build system.