# Does GMP support armv7s?

Tags: gmp, armv7

I tried to use `GMP` for iPad application.

Unfortunately, it failed to running with `XCode 4.5.1` by incorrect architecture of library - `armv7s`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "___gmpz_add", referenced from:
      _main in gmp.o
  "___gmpz_get_str", referenced from:
      _main in gmp.o
  "___gmpz_init_set_str", referenced from:
      _main in gmp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to build library with architecture of **armv7** and run successfully with my XCode but not **armv7s**.

My configuration of `GMP` for **armv7** was:-

> sudo sh ./configure
>   CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
>   CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2"
>   CPP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   -E" LD="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld"
>   CPPFLAGS="-arch **armv7** -isysroot
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   -miphoneos-version-min=4.2" AR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"
>   NM="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nm"
>   NMEDIT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nmedit"
>   LIBTOOL="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool"
>   LIPO="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo"
>   OTOOL="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/otool"
>   RANLIB="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib"
>   STRIP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strip"
>   --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/gmp/5.1.0/**armv7**
>   --host=none-apple-darwin10

For **armv7s**:-

> sudo sh ./configure
>   CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
>   CXX="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2"
>   CPP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   -E" LD="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld"
>   CPPFLAGS="-arch **armv7s** -isysroot
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   -miphoneos-version-min=4.2" AR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"
>   NM="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nm"
>   NMEDIT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/nmedit"
>   LIBTOOL="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool"
>   LIPO="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo"
>   OTOOL="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/otool"
>   RANLIB="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib"
>   STRIP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strip"
>   --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/gmp/5.1.0/**armv7s**
>   --host=none-apple-darwin10

I tried to google to see if `GMP` supports `armv7s` or not but there is no information about this.

Is it not supported or is my configuration before `MAKE` incorrect?

Comment: Why use sudo for configure? Did you try it with either clang or even better a true gcc (not an llvm mix)? Wait, you say you use gcc, but the error message says clang... Couldn't you just remove all those billion variables? And where in the build does it fail, where is the error message coming from?

Comment: I build the GMP successfully by terminal. Unfortunately, error occurred when I use the GMP library inside XCode. The errors coming from XCode when I running my testing apps at IPad 4. For armv7 library that build was work nicely at XCode but armv7s did not.

Comment: Ah, your message sounded like building GMP failed... Ok, so do you actually link with gmp? Can you show the command line xcode is using?

Comment: I am sorry for misleading. I had tried run the testing apps with GMP of armv7 and running successful so I think I linked it with GMP correctly.
Did you meant this?

    leong-hui-mac:bin  <br/>
    leonghui$ xcodebuild -version  <br/>
    Xcode 4.5.1  <br/>
    Build version 4G1004  <br/>

Comment: No, I mean a line that looks like: `clang gmp.o -lgmp -o mytest`. Maybe this question explains how to find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635508/how-can-i-see-the-exact-gcc-command-line-xcode-3-2-6-runs-when-it-builds-an-ipho

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/leonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPoS_IOS-elxesidagybcawcxblhntvvnuioe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
-L/Users/leonghui/Desktop/AIA_Indo_iPoS_iOS_integrated/3party/gmp/armv7/lib -L/Users/leonghui/Desktop/AIA_Indo_iPoS_iOS_integrated/3party/gmp/armv7s/lib

Comment: -F/Users/leonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPoS_IOS-elxesidagybcawcxblhntvvnuioe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos 
-F/Users/leonghui/Desktop/AIA_Indo_iPoS_iOS_integrated 
-filelist /Users/leonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPoS_IOS-elxesidagybcawcxblhntvvnuioe/Build/Intermediates/iPoS_IOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPoS_IOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/ipossg.LinkFileList 
-dead_strip -ObjC -lxml2 -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation

Comment: -lgmp -o /Users/leonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPoS_IOS-elxesidagybcawcxblhntvvnuioe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ipossg.app/ipossg

Comment: @MarcGlisse, is it this you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks. And could you run `nm -D libgmp.so|grep mpz_add` in the directory where libgmp.so is? (or maybe `nm libgmp.a` or some variant) I think it will show `__gmpz_add` with only 2 leading underscores, but I am not sure.

Comment: Note that you have both `.../3party/gmp/armv7/lib` and the v7s version, and the first one has priority, so you may not be linking with the version you think.

Comment: I run the `nm libgmp.a | grep mpz_add`, 
leong-hui-mac:lib leonghui$ nm libgmp.a | grep mpz_add
00000000 T ___gmpz_add
00000000 T ___gmpz_add_ui
00000000 T ___gmpz_addmul
00000308 T ___gmpz_addmul_ui
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_add
         U ___gmpz_add
         U ___gmpz_add
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_add
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_add
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
nm: no name list
         U ___gmpz_add_ui
         U ___gmpz_addmul_ui

Comment: I removed the reference of `.../3party/gmp/armv7/lib`, and linked only with the armv7s version. Unfortunately, it was occurred the same error.